# Does that sentence sound natural "I'm working my way into becoming an English instructor"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

If I'm studying to be an English instructor, can I say "I'm working my way into becoming an English instructor"?

I have searched for the presence of that expression in the language but I could only find "work my way up to"

Answer (score 1):

If your intended meaning is that you are steadily progressing towards a goal, you would say
"I'm working towards becoming an English instructor."

"Working your way into" carries the idea of infiltrating something.
The cancer has worked its way into the kidneys.
I used my charms to work my way into the club.

Comment: My exact intention is to use a more indirect way to say "I'm still searching for a job". @StheRobot

Comment: Ok, so you might say
"I'm pursuing a career as..." or even "I'm pursuing employment 4...". This makes it clearer that you are at the stage of actively looking for a job, without saying bluntly "I dont have a job"

Comment: "I'm working towards becoming an English instructor" sounds good to me! Thank you @StheRobot!